# Adding application alias after manual HRD migration (appengine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am migrating my app to HRD manually (I know there is a the tool for that).
At the end of the migration process I need to route all the domains that are connected to the old app-id to the new app-id (I don't want to redirect).

I know this is done automatically at the end of the migration (when using google's tool)
I want to make an alias myself (manually)

I think there used to be an option in the application settings panel but I can't find it now.

Is there a way to add an application alias?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to contact google support.
They are the only ones who can do it...